# Table Float deletes table lines and just looks ugly

Tags: lyx

I am new to Lyx and get a really ugly table.

My steps:

1. Insert float --> table
2. within the float I then inserted a table.
3. Filled in my numbers and text and saw the PDF file

[image]

What am I doing wrong? The Table is not supposed to look this ugly and I tried to adjust the column width. Should I adjust the height of each cell?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Please edit your posting to show the actual LaTeX code generated by lyx.

Comment: How does one do that?

Comment: Maybe an experienced lyx user can point you in the required direction. (I don't know lyx at all.)

Comment: @EmilKrabbe Welcome to tex.se! Please add minimal example .lyx and corresponding .tex code. To do that please read https://wiki.lyx.org/FAQ/MinimalExample